# make a video your background, but still have icons on desktop

Tags: video

How to make a video your background, but still have icons on desktop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could set the background as a .gif image, and I don't see any reason for your icons to disappear!

If you only have a video, try converting it online using a video to gif converter website.

Comment: thx m8 ill give it a go if it works ill mark u down as a winner